# SPARQL query, remove articles with same titles with different IDs

Tags: sparql

I have a SPARQL query which select unique article IDs.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  ?document 
 WHERE
 { 
   ?obj sem:is_referred_in__document ?doc .
   ?obj ann:label_lemma "lemma"@en .
   ?doc sem:document_ID ?document .
 } LIMIT 40
```

that works fine but the problem is that in my data storage are some same articles with different ID, but have same title so i need to take only one copy of article. Article title i can access with:

```
?doc  rdfs:label ?label
```

So i tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  ?document ?label
 WHERE
 { 
   ?obj sem:is_referred_in__document ?doc .
   ?obj ann:label_lemma "lemma"@en .
   ?doc sem:document_ID ?document .
   ?doc rdfs:label ?label
 } LIMIT 40
```

And this still return me same result as frist query. Any suggestion what i'm doing wrong? As a return for my future process i need only IDs

Comment: It's much easier to understand if you show some sample data (n-Triples or Turtle syntax) + the current result. This would also others to run your query locally and see the current result.

Comment: By the way, it's not clear what you finally want now. The document ID or the article title?

Comment: I have mentioned at the end of question. I need only document ID.

In this picture you can see second query results: http://prntscr.com/f4w8y7 As you can see query return 2 different article ID with same label value. I need only one of them.

Comment: See the answer below from @Stanislav Kralin which is the way to go. Group by the title (resp. the label) and select one of the possible sets of documents per label randomly (via `sample(...)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two ways to slightly modify your second query to make it more adequate to your needs:

**Using [`GROUP BY`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#aggregates)**:

```sql
SELECT ?label  (sample(?document) AS ?id)
WHERE
   { ?obj sem:is_referred_in__document ?doc .
     ?obj ann:label_lemma "lemma"@en .
     ?doc sem:document_ID ?document .
     ?doc rdfs:label ?label 
   } GROUP BY ?label
```

**Using [`FILTER NOT EXISTS`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#negation)**:

```sql
SELECT ?label ?document
WHERE
    { ?obj sem:is_referred_in__document ?doc .
      ?obj ann:label_lemma "lemma"@en .
      ?doc sem:document_ID ?document .
      ?doc rdfs:label ?label .
      FILTER NOT EXISTS
      { ?doc1 sem:document_ID ?document1 .
        ?doc1 rdfs:label ?label .
        FILTER (document1 > document)
      } 
    }
```

I think, these queries are quite self-explanatory…

Probably, you could also tidy up your triplestore, replacing references to duplicated articles in this way (not tested):

```sql
DELETE
  { ?obj sem:is_referred_in__document ?doc1 
  }
INSERT
  { ?obj sem:is_referred_in__document ?doc2
  }
WHERE
   { ?obj sem:is_referred_in__document ?doc1 .
#    ?obj sem:is_referred_in__document ?doc2 .
     ?doc1 sem:document_ID ?document1 .
     ?doc2 sem:document_ID ?document2 .
     ?doc1 rdfs:label ?label .
     ?doc2 rdfs:label ?label .
     FILTER NOT EXISTS
     { ?doc3 sem:document_ID ?document3 .
       ?doc3 rdfs:label ?label .
       FILTER (document3 > document2)
     } 
}
```

Comment: Edit triplestore isn;t and option, i dont have permission to do it, I only can select data, but anyway thank you for your answer

Comment: @Mindaugas, have you tried first two queries from my answer? Do they return what you want or not?

Comment: Yes, first one returns results i need, Thank You.

Comment: Here is one simple question.. i want to improve query by sorting selected article by created date so i add:

ORDER BY DESC(?created_date)

and in the body of the query:

?doc sem:created_date ?created_date    but sorting didint work.

Comment: @Mindaugas, try it: `SELECT ?label  (sample(?document) AS ?id) (sample(?created_date) AS ?created)
WHERE
   { ?obj sem:is_referred_in__document ?doc .
     ?obj ann:label_lemma "lemma"@en .
     ?doc sem:document_ID ?document . ?doc sem:created_date ?created_date .
     ?doc rdfs:label ?label 
   } GROUP BY ?label ORDER BY DESC(?created)`